# sty color missing problem Beamer Poster JHR

Tags: latex, beamer, poster

I am trying to use RJH style in beamer latex poster. However, it meets three errors when compiling. (see below, and screenshot attached)

Anyone knows how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

P.S. the .tex and .sty files were found here: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148558/changing-block-background-color-in-beamerposter

=============================================================================
beamerthemeRJH.sty:31:Package keyval Error: fg undefined ...font{footline}{fg=white,size=\normalsize}
beamerthemeRJH.sty:43:Package keyval Error: bg undefined ...rge,series=\bf, bg=16colorscheme1,fg=white}
beamerthemeRJH.sty:43:Package keyval Error: fg undefined ...rge,series=\bf, bg=16colorscheme1,fg=white}

[image]

Comment: Even when you reference something on [tex.se], why do you still post (La)TeX-related questions here. It's far better-suited on [tex.se]...

Comment: @Werner considering the answer rate of beamer questions on tex.se ( https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1114421/answered-unanswered-questions-for-a-tag-by-month#graph )  I'm not sure this is a good advice

Comment: @samcarter: It went down to only 60%... wonder why that is... perhaps that's the push that's needed for the [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) hero waiting in the shadows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .sty file uses a wrong syntax, colours must be defined in the colour template, not in the font template. This means the two lines

```
\setbeamerfont{footline}{fg=white, size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{example title}{size=\large,series=\bf,bg=i6colorscheme1,fg=white}
```

must be changed to

```
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{example title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}
```

In addition to this incorrect syntax, one should really not longer use the obsolete `\bf` command, replace all occurrences with `\bfseries`

Modified .sty file (to be used as `\usetheme{RJHrepaired}`):

```
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthemeRJHrepaired} % this style was created by Rob J Hyndman and is an adapation of i6dv by David Vilar

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\mode<presentation>

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% custom colors
\definecolor{i6blue}{cmyk}{1,0.305,0,0.06}
\definecolor{i6bluedark}{rgb}{0.0156,0.2578,0.5625} 
\definecolor{i6colorscheme1}{HTML}{FF6518}  % e.g. for block title
\definecolor{i6colorblockbg}{HTML}{0033cc}
\definecolor{i6colorblockfg}{HTML}{FCE94F}
\definecolor{i6colorscheme2}{HTML}{000000}  % e.g. title in headline
\definecolor{i6colorscheme3}{HTML}{C3DFFF}  % e.g. for poster background
\definecolor{i6colorscheme4}{HTML}{000000} 
\definecolor{i6colorschemeHeadline}{HTML}{0033cc}  % for headline bg
\definecolor{i6colorschemeFootline}{HTML}{100D09}  % for headline bg

% headline colors and fonts
\setbeamercolor{headline}{fg=white,bg=i6colorschemeHeadline}
\setbeamercolor{title in headline}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{author in headline}{fg=lightgray}
\setbeamercolor{institute in headline}{fg=lightgray}
\setbeamercolor{logo in headline}{fg=black,bg=lightgray}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=i6colorscheme1}

% footline colors and fonts
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=white,bg=i6colorschemeHeadline}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\normalsize}

% body colors and fonts
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=i6colorscheme3}

% block environment
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=white,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{fg=i6colorblockfg,bg=i6colorblockbg}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}

% example environment
\setbeamercolor*{example title}{fg=white,bg=i6colorscheme1}
\setbeamerfont{example title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=i6colorscheme1}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}  % no navigation on a poster

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
  \vskip.75ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=1cm,colsep*=.75ex]{block title}%
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,sep=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
  }
  \setbeamertemplate{block end}{
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
  \leavevmode

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
                \centering
        \vskip2ex
        \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}\textbf{\LARGE{\inserttitle}}\\[1ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \rule{0pt}{2pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{upper separation line foot}
    \rule{0pt}{2pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=4ex,leftskip=1cm,rightskip=1cm]{footline}%
    \hfill \raisebox{-0.4cm}{\insertfooter}
    \vskip1ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line foot}
    \rule{0pt}{2pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mode<all>

\def\footer#1{\def\insertfooter{#1}}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing out the syntax error. The modified .sty file works well.

Comment: @lslrsgis Good to hear that it is working! Can you please consider marking it as the accepted by clicking on the checkmark ✓? This way other users will know that your problem was solved.

Comment: Additional question is on the figure number. How to change the figure caption from Fig. => Fig.1 (Fig. 2). It seems that the numbers are not generated automatically. Thanks.

Comment: @lslrsgis To get numbered caption add `\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]` to your preamble